# if-else in XML parsing with ElementTree find

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a big input file. I'm just mentioning a sample below:

```
      <metadata-record class='column'>
        <remote-name>Customer Name</remote-name>
        <remote-type>130</remote-type>
        <local-name>[Customer Name]</local-name>
        <parent-name>[Custom SQL Query]</parent-name>
        <remote-alias>Customer Name</remote-alias>
        <ordinal>5</ordinal>
        <local-type>string</local-type>
        <aggregation>Count</aggregation>
        <contains-null>true</contains-null>
        **<collation>LEN_RUS_S2_WO</collation>**
        <attributes>
          <attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;WSTR&quot;</attribute>
        </attributes>
      </metadata-record>

      <metadata-record class='column'>
        <remote-name>Discount</remote-name>
        <remote-type>5</remote-type>
        <local-name>[Discount]</local-name>
        <parent-name>[Custom SQL Query]</parent-name>
        <remote-alias>Discount</remote-alias>
        <ordinal>6</ordinal>
        <local-type>real</local-type>
        <aggregation>Sum</aggregation>
        **<precision>15</precision>**
        <contains-null>true</contains-null>
        <attributes>
          <attribute datatype='string' name='DebugRemoteType'>&quot;R8&quot;</attribute>
        </attributes>
      </metadata-record>
```

I want to write *collation* when it is available, else *precision* tag value. But when I try running this code I'm not able to ever get the latter (even if I'm sure that the corresponding node is present).

This is my code:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import shutil, os
colName  = []
colType  = []
colLname = []
colPname = []
colAlias = []
colOrd   = []
colLtype = []
colagg   = []
colcolla = []
colprec  = []
colcnull = []

xmlTree = et.parse('Input.xml')
xmlRoot = xmlTree.getroot()
for x in xmlRoot.findall('./connection/metadata-records/metadata-record'):
            colName.append(x.find('remote-name').text) 
            colType.append(x.find('remote-type').text) 
            colLname.append(x.find('local-name').text) 
            colPname.append(x.find('parent-name').text) 
            colAlias.append(x.find('remote-alias').text) 
            colOrd.append(x.find('ordinal').text) 
            colLtype.append(x.find('local-type').text) 
            colagg.append(x.find('aggregation').text)
            colcnull.append(x.find('contains-null').text)
            
            if x.find('precision'): 
                colprec.append(x.find('precision').text) 
                print("1")
            else:
                colcolla.append(x.find('collation').text) 
                print("2")
```

but I get the following output, with `Attrubute error`:

```
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-2006350475d2> in <module>
     14                 print("1")
     15             else:
---> 16                 colcolla.append(x.find('collation').text)
     17                 print("2")
     18 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

My output is same as input, for the first metadata record 'collation' tag is there so it should get printed for the next tag precision is there so that should get printed. My output im expecting is as the sample XML that I have pasted above. Now I'm only getting metadata records with collation tag I'm  not getting precision.

Comment: `colName.append(x.find('remote-name').text) if x is not None else None` what is the point of the `if ...` on that line?

Comment: Clearly `x` is never in fact `None`, because if it was, then your `x.find` test would raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Try changing `if x.find('precision'):` to `if x.find('precision') is not None: ` and see if it works.

Comment: @ Jack Fleeting , Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) method of `ElementTree` class

> Returns an element instance or **`None`**.

The conditional `if x.find('precision'):` you are testing is evaluated as true if its argument is equal to the boolean `True`. But even if the `precision` node is found, the returned value won't be a boolean!

You just have to check that the return value of `find` is different from [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None):

```
if x.find('precision') is not None: 
    colprec.append(x.find('precision').text) 
    print("1")
else:
    colcolla.append(x.find('collation').text) 
    print("2")
```

**Output:**

```
2
1
```

Comment: No, absolutely not robbed! +1

Comment: I have added the code and tried but i got the above error. Can you please have a look once ?? Thanks for your help !!

Comment: I have edited my question and posted the error down

Comment: Thanks much @RobertoCaboni , I made a mistake in indentation so i got the error , now rectified . Thanks much for your help !!

Comment: @Aarush nice news. I was just posting to say that I didn't reproduce the issue. Happy to know that you solved it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217819/discussion-between-aarush-and-roberto-caboni).